# Question editor is gone on Stack Overflow (IE9)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, editor, internet-explorer-9

The question WYSIWYG editor has stop working for me in IE9 (32 and 64 bit versions).

It was working earlier this week, and I don't recall installing anything special since then.

The WYSIWYG editor is working with Firefox, and Chrome; it is also working with IE9 for Meta Stack Overflow.

Am I the only one dealing with this issue right now?  Any advice on how to fix this would be welcome.

Comment: obligatory "get a better browser" comment.

Comment: lol... +1 for the better browser comment.  Unfortunately, I have to stick with IE9 for all kind of reasons.

Comment: @Simon: Presumably it's also broken for answers.

Comment: @Al Everett: No, the answers are working as usual.

Comment: That is very strange.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems to be working for me on IE9 on Windows 7, although it took a half-second for the icons to load.

Comment: Oh great!  Now it's working again.  Am I suppose to delete this post now?

Comment: IE9 has been deprecated :-)

Comment: Use Chrome. If you can't install it, get Chrome Portable from PortableApps.com. The Beta/Dev tree installers install to your AppData without admin priv. needed. Well, this is all for Windows anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume this has been fixed. As a side note, we don't support this version of IE, please upgrade your browser if you haven't done so.

Comment: We dropped IE a while ago (following that issue)... I can't tell if it was fixed and honestly, I don't feel like installing IE :)